# Use a grouped field to filter the original table in the summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

## Edit.

**I´ve rewritten the question hoping it makes more sense.**

Given this data:

```
> df
  Cat1 Cat2 Q
1    A    B 1
2    A    C 1
3    B    D 1
4    B    C 1
5    C    C 1
6    C    D 1
```

You can easily `group by` `Cat1` and `sum` `Q` using dplyr:

```
> df %>% group_by(Cat1) %>% summarise(Sum1 = sum(Q))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Cat1   Sum1
  <fct> <dbl>
1 A         2
2 B         2
3 C         2
```

Now, my question is, as a next step, **can you use the groups in the `group by` (i.e. `A`, `B` and `C`) to operate in the original table? For example, how could you `sum` `Q` when `Cat2` equals each group?**

Meaning, for `A` there is no match in `Cat2`, so the sum of `Q` would be `0`. For `B` there is only a match in the first row, so the sum of `Q` would be `1`. For `C` there is a match in the second, the fourth and the fifth row, so the sum of `Q` would be `3`:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Cat1   Sum1   Sum2
  <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A         2      0
2 B         2      1
3 C         2      3
```

Note that this is **not** what I´m asking:

```
> df %>% group_by(Cat1) %>% summarise(Sum1 = sum(Q), Sum2 = sum(Q[Cat1==Cat2]))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Cat1   Sum1  Sum2
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         2     0
2 B         2     0
3 C         2     1
```

@antoine-sac propose in the comments to duplicate `df` and do a left join on `Cat1(Grouped) = Cat2`. Of course this would solve the problem, but it´s not the question I´m trying to answer.

Code:

```
Cat1 <- c("A","A","B","B","C","C")
Cat2 <- c("B","C","D","C","C","D")
Cat1 <- factor(Cat1, levels = c("A","B","C","D"))
Cat2 <- factor(Cat2, levels = c("A","B","C","D"))
Q <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1)
df <- data.frame(Cat1, Cat2, Q)
```

Comment: So... you want to group by end date? I can't make sense of your explanations but your last table is what you'd get grouping by end date and summing, completely ignoring the start date. Your question is extremely unclear though.

Comment: @antoine-sac I´ll try to rewrite the question to make it more clear. I can´t group by End date. The production data is more complex, I have to group by Start date and make a number of operations... I´d like to add another column where I sum Quantity only when the End date equals "each Start group". For example, for  Start == 2019-01-03 I would need to match the 4º and 10º row of the original table.

Comment: Sounds like you need to have a separate data.frame with (End, Quantity). You can do whatever you need to do grouped by Start date, then left join the quantity on `Start = End`.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the comments. Can´t you access a group of a group by as an independent object to use it later then, i.e. to filter in a summarise? Seems a bit redundant having to duplicate the data.

Comment: @antoine-sac I´ve rewritten the question. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Brilliant, super clear now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a `join` is the cleanest way to do it. Think about yourself reading your code again in 6 months: you want the meaning of your code to be obvious.

```r
library("dplyr")

df <- read.table(text = "  Cat1 Cat2 Q
1    A    B 1
2    A    C 1
3    B    D 1
4    B    C 1
5    C    C 1
6    C    D 1", stringsAsFactor = FALSE)

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(Cat1) %>%
  summarise(Sum1 = sum(Q))

df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Cat2) %>%
  summarise(Sum2 = sum(Q))

full_join(df1, df2, by = c("Cat1" = "Cat2")) %>%
  tidyr::replace_na(list(Sum1 = 0, Sum2 = 0))

# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   Cat1   Sum1  Sum2
#   <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A         2     0
# 2 B         2     1
# 3 C         2     3
# 4 D         0     2
```

With a `full_join`, you keep all values in `Cat1` or `Cat2` (A, B, C , D) but you can use a `left_join` (to keep A, B, C), a `right_join` (to keep B, C, D) or an `inner_join` (to keep B, C).

These are respectively the values in `Cat1`, in `Cat2` or both in `Cat1` *and* `Cat2`.

It may seem painful, especially if you have a lot of categories, but if you have to do it more than once, it is actually easy to automate in a function.

EDIT: actually it is not easy at all if you want to use dplyr due to non-standard evaluation. Here's how you'd do it:

```r
sum_cats <- function(df, cat1, cat2, value) {
  cat1 <- enquo(cat1)
  cat2 <- enquo(cat2)
  value <- enquo(value)

  sum1 <- paste0("Sum_", quo_name(cat1))
  df1 <- df %>%
    rename(cat = !! cat1) %>%
    group_by(cat) %>%
    summarise(!! sum1 := sum(!! value))

  sum2 <- paste0("Sum_", quo_name(cat2))
  df2 <- df %>%
    rename(cat = !! cat2) %>%
    group_by(cat) %>%
    summarise(!! sum2 := sum(!! value))

  full_join(df1, df2, by = "cat") %>%
    tidyr::replace_na(rlang::list2(!! sum1 := 0, !! sum2 := 0))
}
```

Now you can just call `sum_cats` to do all the work:

```r
df %>%
  sum_cats(Cat1, Cat2, Q)
#   cat   Sum_Cat1 Sum_Cat2
#   <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 A            2        0
# 2 B            2        1
# 3 C            2        3
# 4 D            0        2
```

Comment: I´ve tried this and @Jimbou answer with production data and the join approach is much faster, so if you can load your data in memory twice it is better.

Comment: @AleG Note that `df1` and `df2` are smaller than `df` (how much smaller depends on your actual data, but it could be several orders of magnitude) so you're not quite doubling memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Cat1) %>% 
  summarise(sum1 = sum(Q),
            sum2 = sum(ifelse(.$Cat2 == Cat1[1], Q, 0)))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Cat1   sum1  sum2
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A         2     0
2 B         2     1
3 C         2     3
```

By using the `.$` you will compare and sum up the ungrouped original data.

Comment: could you care to explain how that works? Or point me to some reference. What is the [1] in Cat1[1] for? Is it for accessing the grouped Cat1? And how the .$ works? Like "any dataframe" where Cat2 is an object?

Comment: It should be `ifelse(.$Cat2 == Cat1[1], .$Cat2, 0)`

Comment: @antoine-sac not `ifelse(.$Cat2 == Cat1[1], Q, 0)`? sorry but I don´t get this syntax quite well yet

Comment: edited my answer. I thought you want to sum up the occurence of the letters.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could construct a new column and summarise from the new column:

```
df %>% mutate(new_Quantity=ifelse(Start == End, Quantity,0)) %>% group_by(Start) %>% summarise(Sum = sum(new_Quantity))
```